# UWP setting themeresource acrylic in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, fluent-design, acrylic-material

I have a UWP app and I want to upgrade it to fluent design system. I have created a new project using Windows Template Studio and my navigation is with Pivot.

Now I want to put **acrylic background** on the **header of the pivot**. as mentioned in the design guidelines of uwp it is recommended to use 70 percent acrylic in this scenario.

So I tried to use 70 percent acrylic with following code.

```
private void MainPivot_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush"))
    {
        MainPivot.Background = Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush"] as AcrylicBrush;
    }

}
```

Where MainPivot is the pivot I am using and this loaded method is loaded event for that pivot.

The problem is that it works only for either **Light** or **Dark** Theme (depends which theme was set during last run of the app), but when app is running and I change theme and switch between light or dark themes, it doesn't work well for both themes, for example if I make the theme dark the acrylic color remains white and pivot header text is also white hence creating disturbed UI.

Also the **FallBack Color** doesn't make sense either, for light theme fallback color is black (which blends in with black text) and same problem occurs in dark theme.

The reason I am doing it from code behind because the min project target of my app is creators update which doesn't have acrylic brush.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml) provides a way to use the `ApiInformation.IsTypePresent` method in XAML markup. This lets you set properties and instantiate objects in markup based on the presence of an API without needing to use code behind.

To use a conditional method in XAML, you must first declare a conditional XAML namespace at the top of your page.

```
xmlns:IsAcrylicBrushPresent="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsTypePresent(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush)"
xmlns:IsAcrylicBrushNotPresent="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsTypeNotPresent(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush)"
```

After the namespace is defined, we can use the namespace prefix to the `Background` property of your `Grid` to qualify it as a property that should be set conditionally at runtime.

```
<Grid Name="MainPivot" IsAcrylicBrushPresent:Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush}"  IsAcrylicBrushNotPresent:Background="Red">
```

If the device supports `AcrylicBrush`, it will use the SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush. If not, it will use the Red color.

Comment: I am having an error "property background is set multiple times"

Comment: @touseef Have you set target to Window 10 Fall Creators Update when you build?

Comment: yes I have, but now it works for me I have just set conditional background property only once for acrylic background and if that isnt present, then it automatically gives me transparent background which works fine for me